# How add HDFS connector to Kafka Connect API?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I'm new using Kafka Connect features and I'm getting difficulties on how configure Kafka and HDFS with Kafka Connect.

I've been following the tutorial from Debezium website, where I could test new events and see how the system works. Once in the tutorial they explained how we can create a connector between MySql and Kafka, I tried do the same but for the HDFS.

I've done my research online and launch the following command:

```
*curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name":"hdfs-sink","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
"tasks.max":1,
"topics":"dbserver1,dbserver1.inventory.products,dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand,dbserver1.inventory.customers,dbserver1.inventory.orders",
"hdfs.url":"hdfs://172.18.0.2:9870",
"flush.size":3,
"logs.dir":"logs",
"topics.dir":"kafka",
"format.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat",
"partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
"partition.field.name":"day"}}'*
```

In this command I've added the topic that where generated automatically by Kafka, the URL I tried to use the IP address from the container namenode (which I not sure if this is correct). Over all I'm testing, but the final goal here is get every event into HDFS.

*`{"error_code":500,"message":"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-activemq/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.gcs.GcsSinkConnector', version='5.0.3', encodedVersion=5.0.3, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-gcs/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-ibmmq/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-activemq/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector', version='5.3.1', encodedVersion=5.3.1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-s3/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-s3/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector, name='io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector', version='null', encodedVersion=null, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-datagen/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='5.3.1-ccs', encodedVersion=5.3.1-ccs, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/usr/share/java/kafka/'}"}`*

This is the given error by the terminal, I believe the plugin for HDFS is not installed properly(I've followed many examples online, but still not sure if is correctly installed).

I'm not sure if is really necessary have this plugin from Confluent?

I don't know if HDFS installed from docker it's also a good idea?

Hope you share some of your knowledge on this issue, thanks in advance.

Tutorial link: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/tutorial.html

Comment: I downloaded the Confluent-Hub to my local machine and then installed the hdfs plugin on my local machine.

After that, I created a kafka user and change the owner and the group on all contents of the plugin and moved to the Kafka Connect container and the restarted the container, and he was just installed.

Thanks to all the answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDFS2 Sink Connector is deprecated and removed from the Confluent Platform installation.

You can still find it and install it from Confluent Hub, and I would recommend using the official Apache Kafka site to learn about the core of Kafka Connect rahter than elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

There is an issue with plugin installation. So first of all, please check it using the Kafka Connect REST Interface (see details [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#get--connector-plugins-)). And then you can install connector [manually](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/install.html#install-connector-manually).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link on Confluent's staging docs for HDFS 2 Sink Connector:
 https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html

It covers almost everything and will also help you how to work around if you are using Confluent Platform.

A docker image provides a reliable way to work with HDFS. Use this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/